# Toggle a class in Vue.js without touching the other present classes

Tags: vue.js

I have an HTML element, to which several classes were assigned during runtime, like so:

```
<element class="class1 class2 class3 classN"></element>
```

Using Vue.js, I want to toggle `class1` dependent on the data model. I could write:

```
<element v-bind:class="{ class1: ifClass1 }"></element>
```

The problem is, that this binding will *delete all the other present classes* (`class2` to `classN`).
But I can not add these classes to the binding, since they were added dynamically during the runtime. I do not even know these classes beforehand, since they are added by an external framework.

How can I *toggle just a single class* in Vue.js?

Comment: You can combine a static class with a bound class. `<element class="class2 class3" :class="{class1: ifClass1">`.

Comment: `class="class2 class3"` is no option for me, since it's not me who is adding these classes, but an external framework during runtime.

Comment: When are the classes added in relation to when the template is compiled?

Comment: The classes are added after the whole initialization process is finished. I just tested it by hand: When the website was loaded, I added a `class2` to the element. As soon as the `ifClass1` predicate changes, the `class` of `<element>` is set to `"class1"` or `""`, but in both cases `class2` gets lost.

Comment: You'll probably have to resort to DOM manipulation then with a watch on `ifClass1`.

Comment: That should work. So the answer is that there is no solution for this problem in Vue.js.

Comment: I wouldn't characterize this as a Vue problem per se. The library is manipulating the DOM without Vue knowing about it. Without somehow letting Vue know about changes (sometimes this is manageable with a wrapper component and events) you'll have to manage it yourself. If the library added classes *before* the template was compiled, Vue would know about them. Without concrete information though, its difficult to say what the best approach is.

Comment: I just had to do something similar, ended up using :class="position"  The value of position was a single string containing the names of several utility classes generated dynamically.  position = "bottom right p-20".   Might work here?